# How to generate a unique list of 3 character prefixes

Tags: python, list, combinations

How to make the top list to the below output in python 3:

```
['abc', 'def', 'ghi']


['adg', 'adh', 'adi', 'aeg', 'aeh', 'aei', 'afg', 'afh', 'afi', 'bdg', 'bdh', 'bdi', 'beg', 'beh', 'bei', 'bfg', 'bfh', 'bfi', 'cdg', 'cdh', 'cdi', 'ceg', 'ceh', 'cei', 'cfg', 'cfh', 'cfi']
```

If possible, can this be solved using a for loop?

Comment: try using `itertools.permutation`; there should be 9p3 total combinations. https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for `itertools.product`:

```
from itertools import product

lst = ['abc', 'def', 'ghi']

print( [''.join(c) for c in product(*lst)] )
```

Prints:

```
['adg', 'adh', 'adi', 'aeg', 'aeh', 'aei', 'afg', 'afh', 'afi', 'bdg', 'bdh', 'bdi', 'beg', 'beh', 'bei', 'bfg', 'bfh', 'bfi', 'cdg', 'cdh', 'cdi', 'ceg', 'ceh', 'cei', 'cfg', 'cfh', 'cfi']
```

Comment: is it possible to do this without using the itertools lib?

Comment: @KevinHao The manual page for [`itertools.product()`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) has sample implementation for the function. You can use that

Answer (score 2):

What you want is the product of each list `values[0] * values[1] * values[2]`

```
from itertools import product
values = ['abc', 'def', 'ghi']
result = list(map("".join, product(*values)))
```

## [`CODE DEMO`](https://repl.it/repls/BriefIdioticTasks)

Comment: is it possible to do this without using the itertools lib?